# Custom Grid Query in Rally with Multiple OR Clauses

Tags: rally

I'm trying to write a query in Rally that will show me all the defects for several projects, but every time I save the query I get the message "Could not parse: Error parsing expression -- expected ")" but saw "OR" instead."

Here is the actual query:

```
((((Project.Name = "Project A") OR (Project.Name = "Project B")) OR (Project.Name = "Project C")) OR (Project.Name = "Project D"))
```

I checked Rally's so-called Help and it seems to me that everything is set up correctly, but maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query syntax and parentheses groupings look fine. I tested your exact string above in a Custom Grid and it parses fine - no "Could not parse..." error. Maybe compare the exact query you are using against your sample above? Complex AND's and OR's can definitely be frustrating. If you miss a parenthesis or spaces around operators, the query engine will complain.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now without me making any changes to it... don't know why it wasn't earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

fyi, I just found that doing a page reload in the browser forces the changed query expression to be evaluated, whereas simply saving the modified query does *not* reliably re-evaluate the changed query.

The symptom I observed was that query results continued to complain about the *previous* query string, even though I had replaced parts of the query with different named fields, etc. This made me suspect browser caching, and when flushing cache did not help, then I did browser page reload, which worked perfectly.

So if your browser page was reloaded between when you were having the problem and later when it started working, then this might explain why.

From About link: Rally Build: master-9274 , Browser Type: firefox/19.0, rv:19.0